# How to retrieve data from a one to one mapped entity after a filter is applied on to the mapped entity's attribute spring

Tags: spring, hibernate

How to retrieve data from a one to one mapped entity after a filter is applied on to the mapped entity's attribute.

This is my Hotel Entity Class..

```
package com.springmvcweb.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "HOTEL", schema = "HOTEL")
public class HotelEntity implements Serializable{
private long hotelId;
private String hotelName;
private String hotelDescription;
private String hotelWebsite;
private Long hotelPhoneNo;
private String hotelEmail;
private Long hotelStarRating;

private AddressEntity addressEntity;
private CategoryEntity categoryEntity;
private List<AmenityEntity> amenitiesList;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "HOTEL_AMENITY", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "HOTEL_ID", referencedColumnName = "HOTEL_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "AMENITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "AMENITY_ID")})
public List<AmenityEntity> getAmenitiesList() {
    return amenitiesList;
}

public void setAmenitiesList(List<AmenityEntity> amenitiesList) {
    this.amenitiesList = amenitiesList;
}

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOTEL_ADDRESS_ID")
public AddressEntity getAddressEntity() {
    return addressEntity;
}

public void setAddressEntity(AddressEntity addressEntity) {
    this.addressEntity = addressEntity;
}

@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "HOTEL_CATEGORY_ID")
public CategoryEntity getCategoryEntity() {
    return categoryEntity;
}

public void setCategoryEntity(CategoryEntity categoryEntity) {
    this.categoryEntity = categoryEntity;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "HOTEL_ID")
public long getHotelId() {
    return hotelId;
}

public void setHotelId(long hotelId) {
    this.hotelId = hotelId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOTEL_NAME")
public String getHotelName() {
    return hotelName;
}

public void setHotelName(String hotelName) {
    this.hotelName = hotelName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOTEL_DESCRIPTION")
public String getHotelDescription() {
    return hotelDescription;
}

public void setHotelDescription(String hotelDescription) {
    this.hotelDescription = hotelDescription;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOTEL_WEBSITE")
public String getHotelWebsite() {
    return hotelWebsite;
}

public void setHotelWebsite(String hotelWebsite) {
    this.hotelWebsite = hotelWebsite;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOTEL_PHONE_NO")
public Long getHotelPhoneNo() {
    return hotelPhoneNo;
}

public void setHotelPhoneNo(Long hotelPhoneNo) {
    this.hotelPhoneNo = hotelPhoneNo;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOTEL_EMAIL")
public String getHotelEmail() {
    return hotelEmail;
}

public void setHotelEmail(String hotelEmail) {
    this.hotelEmail = hotelEmail;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "HOTEL_STAR_RATING")
public Long getHotelStarRating() {
    return hotelStarRating;
}

public void setHotelStarRating(Long hotelStarRating) {
    this.hotelStarRating = hotelStarRating;
}

public void addAmenities(AmenityEntity amenityEntity){
    if(amenitiesList==null){
        amenitiesList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    amenitiesList.add(amenityEntity);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "HotelEntity{" +
            "hotelId=" + hotelId +
            ", hotelName='" + hotelName + '\'' +
            ", hotelDescription='" + hotelDescription + '\'' +
            ", hotelWebsite='" + hotelWebsite + '\'' +
            ", hotelPhoneNo=" + hotelPhoneNo +
            ", hotelEmail='" + hotelEmail + '\'' +
            ", hotelStarRating=" + hotelStarRating +
            ", addressEntity=" + addressEntity +
            ", categoryEntity=" + categoryEntity +
            ", amenitiesList=" + amenitiesList +
            '}';
}
```

}

This is AddressEntity Class:

```
package com.springmvcweb.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS", schema = "HOTEL")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {
private long addressId;
private String addressLine1;
private String addressLine2;
private String cityName;
private String stateName;
private String countryName;
private Long pincode;

@Id
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
public long getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE1")
public String getAddressLine1() {
    return addressLine1;
}

public void setAddressLine1(String addressLine1) {
    this.addressLine1 = addressLine1;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "ADDRESS_LINE2")
public String getAddressLine2() {
    return addressLine2;
}

public void setAddressLine2(String addressLine2) {
    this.addressLine2 = addressLine2;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "CITY_NAME")
public String getCityName() {
    return cityName;
}

public void setCityName(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "STATE_NAME")
public String getStateName() {
    return stateName;
}

public void setStateName(String stateName) {
    this.stateName = stateName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
public String getCountryName() {
    return countryName;
}

public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
    this.countryName = countryName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "PINCODE")
public Long getPincode() {
    return pincode;
}

public void setPincode(Long pincode) {
    this.pincode = pincode;
}
```

}

Now I want to retrieve all those hotels filtered by their location(say cityname or statename) and I'm using query like this:

```
@Override
public List<HotelEntity> getHotelsByLocation(String location) {
try{
    session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}catch (Exception e){
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
}

Query query = session.createQuery("from HotelEntity where HotelEntity.addressEntity.cityName " +
        "like :location");
query.setParameter("location",location);
return query.getResultList();
```

}
Also I've used FetchType as EAGER in the HotelEntity OneToOne Mapping like this:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "HOTEL_ADDRESS_ID")
public AddressEntity getAddressEntity() {
    return addressEntity;
}
```

Right now it is giving me a null pointer exception. Please guide.

Comment: Could you frame the question a bit better? It's a bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@OneToOne` relationship is eagerly fetched anyway so adding that information is redundant.

Regarding the query I would form it like the following:

```
 " select he from HotelEntity he 
 "  inner join he.addressEntity ae"
 " where ae.cityName like :location");
```